# Is there a general way to replace a value in a nested dictionary with varying degrees of nested levels in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

So in Python 3.6.8, I have this set of configuration files loaded into dictionaries that need to be modified according to the data in my sensitivity analysis file. The sensitivity analysis files are formatted to generate a tuple with 1) another tuple with a path containing the key at each level within the dictionary and 2) to value the lowest levels needs to change to.

The problem that occur is that the configuration file data is given at varying nested levels within the dictionary as follows:

```
modify_instructions = (("key_L1", "key_L2",..., "key_Ln"), "value_to_change_lowest_level_to")
config_dat = 
    {
          "key_L1a" : {
                      "key_L2a": "value_at_L2"
                      "key_L2b : {
                                      "key_L3": "value_at_L3"
                                  }
                      }
          "key_L1b" : "value_at_L1"
                    
    }
```

I need to find a robust way to be able to replace the values at each level based on the length of defined dictionary key.

Currently I have the extremely inflexible solution, as I know the key level is never lower than 4:

```
def modify_data(modify_instruction, config_data):
        
    adaptor_key = modify_instruction[0]
    adaptor_parameter = modify_instruction[1]
    degree_nested = len(adaptor_key)

    if degree_nested == 1:
        config_dat[adaptor_key[0]] = adaptor_parameter
    elif degree_nested == 2:
        config_dat[adaptor_key[0]][adaptor_key[1]] = adaptor_parameter
    elif degree_nested == 3:
        config_dat[adaptor_key[0]][adaptor_key[1]][adaptor_key[2]] = adaptor_parameter
    elif degree_nested == 4:
        config_dat[adaptor_key[0]][adaptor_key[1]][adaptor_key[2]][adaptor_key[3]] = adaptor_parameter
    else:
        raise TypeError("Amount of nested entries is incompatible -- this script only recognizes "
                        "a maximum of 4 nested levels in the base config file")

    return config_dat
```

But I realize I will face a similar issue in many more config files, with likely even lower nested dictionary levels.

Consequently, I want to find a bit more general way to address this issue, rather then write a 100 `elif` statements. Is there any more general way to adapt values at varying degree of nested data within a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule, if you have a recursive data structure, a recursive program is worth considering. That way, the code never needs to know how deep in the data structure it is.

```
config_dat = {'key_L1a': {'key_L2a': 'value_at_L2', 'key_L2b': {'key_L3': 'value_at_L3'}}, 'key_L1b': 'value_at_L1'}

def modify(data, instruction):
    key, new_data = instruction[0][0], instruction[1]
    if isinstance(data[key], dict):
        modify(data[key], (instruction[0][1:],new_data))
    else:
        data[key]=instruction[1]


modify_instruction = (('key_L1a', 'key_L2b', 'key_L3'), 'value_to_change_lowest_level_to')
modify(config_dat, modify_instruction)
print(config_dat)

modify_instruction = (('key_L1a', 'key_L2a'), 'new L2a')
modify(config_dat, modify_instruction)
print(config_dat)
```

Output

```
{'key_L1a': {'key_L2a': 'value_at_L2', 'key_L2b': {'key_L3': 'value_to_change_lowest_level_to'}}, 'key_L1b': 'value_at_L1'}
{'key_L1a': {'key_L2a': 'new L2a', 'key_L2b': {'key_L3': 'value_to_change_lowest_level_to'}}, 'key_L1b': 'value_at_L1'}
```

In the real world a function like this will probably need validation to trap errors in the instructions. For example, the number of keys in the instruction should match the depth of the nesting at that point.

Answer (score 0):

i think `exec` can be use here but i would warning that experience programmer suggest to avoid using `eval`  & `exec` for best practices . find nested level make string to access that dictionary and simply execute dynamically use exception to handle error

```
def modify_data(modify_instruction, config_data):      
  adaptor_key = modify_instruction[0]
  adaptor_parameter = modify_instruction[1]
  level = len(adaptor_key)

  main_var = 'config_data'
  rest_part = ''.join([f"[adaptor_key[{num}]]" for num in range(level)])
  exec_code = f"{main_var}{rest_part} = '{adaptor_parameter}'"
  print(exec_code)

  try:
    exec(exec_code)
  except TypeError as err:
    print(err,":only string present as value not dictionary")
  except KeyError as err:
    print(err,"key is not present is dictionary")

  return config_data
```